# Is it possible to set the multiple tableviews in one screen at a time in iphone

Tags: iphone, xcode, uitableview

I am beginner to iphone.I need to develope the screen as shown in the attached file.All the values like Airfare,Flight to Newyork,$400 etc are comming from the database.In this screen Airfare,cab/Taxi are the types ,displayed in the different cell.It can be possible using one tableview or multiple tableviews.Please give me suggestion.[image]

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to make two tableviews. Because you can implement this functionality in a single table view. Make one tableView Object as...

```
UITableView *tableView;
```

After it make number of sections as much number of categories(AirFare,Cab/Taxi) you have as shown:-

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfSections:(NSInteger)section  
{     
 return [category count]; 
}
```

After it give them Titles as:-

```
- (NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section 
{
if (section == 0)
 {    
 return @"header one";
 } 
}
```

Thats it after this perform the functionality o a click of certain row as:-

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{    
}
```

So you can implement your functionality in a single tableView. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your response.but only one header section is possible for the tableview but I need multiple titles(headers).Please give me suggestion.

Comment: No dude you can give multiple titles.Each title for each section is possible. :)

Answer (score 2):

yes , it is very much possible.  You can create as many instances as you like (unless you run out of memory). You can distinguish between the tableViews in the delgate method calls by distinguishing between them using the arguments that come along...

see like this...

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (tableView==tableView1){
//then do something
}else if (tableView==tableView2){
//then do something else.
}
}
```

hoping this helps... :)